# How to speed up a For-loop

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

My code is the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Off[FindRoot::lstol]

Vn = (-G*Mn)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + cn^2];
Vd = (-G*Md)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (s + h)^2];
Vb = (G*Mb)/(2*a)*(ArcSinh[(x - a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)] - 
                   ArcSinh[(x + a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)]);
Vh = (-G*Mh)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + ch^2];
Vt = Vn + Vd + Vb + Vh;

G = 1; Mn = 400; cn = 0.25;
Md = 7000; s = 3; h = 0.175;
Mb = 3500; a = 2.5; c = 1;
Mh = 20000; ch = 20;
Ωb = 4.5;
E0 = -3245;
```

The initial data list

```
data0 = Table[{ϕ, L}, {ϕ, -π, π, 0.01}, {L, -110, 190, 1}];
ICs = Flatten[data0, 1];
norb = Length[ICs];
Print["N = ", norb]
```

Now I need to filter them using a `For` loop in order to obtain the valid initial conditions

```
data = {};
For[j = 1, j <= norb, j++, 
    ϕ0 = ICs[[j, 1]]; 
    L0 = ICs[[j, 2]];
    vt = L0/R0;

    x0 = R0*Cos[ϕ0];
    y0 = R0*Sin[ϕ0];
    px0 = -vt*Sin[ϕ0];
    py0 = vt*Cos[ϕ0];  
    H = 1/2*(px^2 + py^2) + Vt - Ωb*(x*py - y*px);
    H0 = H /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, px -> px0, py -> py0};

    sol = FindRoot[H0 == E0, {R0, 5}];
    R00 = R0 /. sol[[1]];
    E00 = H0 /. {R0 -> R00};
    Which[E00 == E0, AppendTo[data, {R00, ϕ0, L0}]]
];
```

The correct grid on the (ϕ, L)-plane is the following

[image]

As you can see, not all `ICs` are allowed since there are forbidden (white) regions on the grid. For all allowed initial conditions I know the triplet `{ϕ, L, R}`.

However the `For` loop requires a substantial amount of time in order to check all the initial conditions of the initial list.

Is there a way to speed up the procedure?

Comment: Can't you just generate valid initial conditions to begin with? Generating a lot of pairs and then filtering them will have much worse complexity than a code that only generates valid initial conditions to begin with.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer But I don't know beforehand which are the valid initial conditions. The filtering reveals the valid initial conditions.

Comment: All of these assignments are being done in the `For` loop which is adding substantial overhead. I would symbolically compute `H0` then do a replacement like `{phi0 -> #1, L0 -> #2}` and apply the result to `ICs`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I don't exactly understand what you mean. Could you explain it further or post an answer?

Comment: I'll post some code in a few minutes if I get some decent performance. Essentially, it seems you are checking if `FindRoot` indeed gives a root up to machine precision?

Comment: But `FindRoot` takes quite a bit of time, about 1-2 seconds per 1000 phi-L pairs. That, actually, doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: What is `R0`? Should it be the same as `\[Phi]0`?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer `R0` here is a parameter with respect to which a root is found (at least as presented in the code)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP There must be a way to reduce the CPU time. The equivalent FORTRAN code requires about 2 sec (!!!) to check the 390000 initial conditions.

Comment: There is still something I'm missing. You have one equation, namely `H0 == E0`, and you have three unknowns, `R0`, `\[Phi]` and `L0`. That means that, for every choice of two of them, you should be able to find the third from the equation, at least `L0` which `H0` only depends upon quadratically.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer `H0` is a function of `\[Phi]`, `L0` and `R0`. At the beginning of the FOR loop `\[Phi]` and `L0` get their values, while `FindRoot` gives the value of `R0`.

Comment: Vaggelis_Z Could you explain in words what your code is trying to accomplish? I can't quite follow the logic, and I would still think that @Marius 's suggestion (generate the "right" numbers at the outset) might be a more effective way to go. Also, if you already have FORTRAN code that does what you want in 2 seconds, why don't you construct an interface to that, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP You disappeared! Any luck reducing the speed? Anything less than 5min would be great!

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z the bottleneck is the `FindRoot` (alternatives with `FindMinimum` are also possible). I can see, that you need to find simply a presence of a root and only then actualy find the `R0` which gives that root, however I cannot think of a way to get a simple and fast `RootExistsQ` function. I'm curious, what is that FORTRAN code you talk of that can solve 400000 equations in 2 seconds.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP In a previous comment you proposed to symbolically solve `H0` and then replace `{phi0 -> #1, L0 -> #2}`. Will that be faster? If so, can you explain it further? Do you want a copy of the FORTRAN code?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, at first I thought, that using functions and mapping instead of for-oops would offer a significant speed increase, however I realized later, that the main problem is the `FindRoot` function which is quite slow.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I got a pretty fast solution posted below, though not as fast as you claim the FORTRAN code to be, but still, 20 seconds or so.

Comment: Also in your recent edit of the OP you state that you know the triplets (phi, L, R) for the allowed initial conditions. If you KNOW them, why do you need to check or solve anything?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I know them after the For loop not beforehand!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE 09.11.15**

As @Marius has shown, it is quite easy to get an evenly spaced grid on `ϕ, R0` for values of `L0`. First the equation `H0 == E0` needs to be solved analytically for `L0`. Introduce initial conditions:

```
Vn = (-G*Mn)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + cn^2];
Vd = (-G*Md)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (s + h)^2];
Vb = (G*Mb)/(2*a)*(ArcSinh[(x - a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)] - 
                   ArcSinh[(x + a)*(y^2 + c^2)^(-1/2)]);
Vh = (-G*Mh)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + ch^2];
Vt = Vn + Vd + Vb + Vh;

G = 1; Mn = 400; cn = 0.25;
Md = 7000; s = 3; h = 0.175;
Mb = 3500; a = 2.5; c = 1;
Mh = 20000; ch = 20;
Ωb = 4.5;
E0 = -3245;

vt = L0/R0;

x0 = R0*Cos[ϕ0];
y0 = R0*Sin[ϕ0];
px0 = -vt*Sin[ϕ0];
py0 = vt*Cos[ϕ0];  
H = 1/2*(px^2 + py^2) + Vt - Ωb*(x*py - y*px);
H0 = H /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, px -> px0, py -> py0};
```

Now solve:

```
sol = Solve[H0 == E0, L0] // FullSimplify;
```

In order to speed things up, let's get this into compiled form:

```
comp1 = With[{sol1 = L0 /. First@sol /. {ϕ0 -> #, R0 -> #2}}, 
   Compile[{ϕ0, R0}, Evaluate[sol1 & @@ {ϕ0, R0}]]];
comp2 = With[{sol2 = L0 /. Last@sol /. {ϕ0 -> #, R0 -> #2}}, 
   Compile[{ϕ0, R0}, Evaluate[sol2 & @@ {ϕ0, R0}]]];
```

Note the injection of parameters inside the compiled function (otherwise `ϕ0, R0` in the compiled function are not the same symbols as `\Phi[0], R0` in the solution. To avoid symbolic evaluation of compiled functions and also to handle the removable singularity at `R0 == 0` augment this with a pattern matching only numeric arguments:

```
expr1[ϕ0_?NumericQ, R0_?NumericQ /; R0 > 0] := comp1[ϕ0, R0];
expr2[ϕ0_?NumericQ, R0_?NumericQ /; R0 > 0] := comp2[ϕ0, R0];
expr1[ϕ0_, 0.] = 0; expr2[ϕ0_, 0.] = 0;
```

Let's plot these solutions for some arbitrary `ϕ0`, for example `0.5`:

```
ListPlot[{{expr1[.5, #], #} & /@ Range[0., 5., .01], {expr2[.5, #], #} & /@ Range[0., 5., .01]}]
```

> [image: L0(R0)]

Blue is one branch of the solutions for `L0`, orange is another. And the points are evenly spaced on `R0`. But we want this the other way round. In fact, if we are thinking of `R0` as a function of `L0` and not the other way round, we see, that for several values of `L0` there are two possible `R0`. Let's pick the lower branch.

```
ListPlot[{
  With[{tab = {expr1[.5, #], #} & /@ Range[0., 5., .01]},
   Pick[tab, {True}~
     Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# < 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])]],
  With[{tab = {expr2[.5, #], #} & /@ Range[0.01, 5., .01]}, 
   Pick[tab, {True}~
     Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# > 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])]]}]
```

> [image: Bottom branch]

What I'm doing here, is picking only those elements of the first branch where for increasing `R0` `L0` decreases (as soon as it starts increasing we are in the upper branch of solutions) and similarly, increasing `R0` -> increasing `L0` in the second branch of `L0(R0)`. The following expression will now simply yield a list of values for the lower branch in order of increasing `L0`:

```
With[{ϕ0 = #}, 
   With[{tab = {expr1[ϕ0, #], #} & /@ Range[0., 5., .01]},
     Pick[
       tab, {True}~
        Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# < 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])] // 
      Reverse]~Join~
    With[{tab = {expr2[ϕ0, #], #} & /@ Range[0.01, 5., .01]},
     Pick[
      tab, {True}~
       Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# > 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])]]] &[.5]
```

I've used an outer `With` to make this into a pure function which takes the value of `ϕ0` as an argument and avoids conflict between inner and outer slots along the way.

Let's save this table for each value of `ϕ0` from `Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.01]`:

```
With[{ϕ0 = Round[#, 0.01]},
   r0tab[ϕ0] = 
    With[{tab = {expr1[ϕ0, #], #} & /@ Range[0., 5., .01]},
      Pick[tab, {True}~Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# < 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])]
        // Reverse]
    ~Join~
    With[{tab = {expr2[ϕ0, #], #} & /@ Range[0.01, 5., .01]},
      Pick[tab, {True}~Join~(Composition[TrueQ, (# > 0 &), First] /@ Differences[tab])]]
   ] & /@ Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.01];
```

This took roughly 10 seconds, already not too bad, (though I'm curious, how can this be done in a mere 2 seconds even with FORTRAN).

Now the table for each value of `\[Phi0]` needs to be resampled to get an even grid on `L0`:

```
With[{ϕ0 = Round[#, 0.01]}, 
     With[{min = Ceiling@First@First@r0tab[ϕ0], 
       max = Floor@First@Last@r0tab[ϕ0], 
       func = Interpolation@r0tab[ϕ0]},
      Table[{ϕ0, L0, func[L0]}, {L0, min, max, 3.}]]] & /@ 
   Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.05] // Flatten[#, 1] & // ListPointPlot3D
```

> [image: Result]

Adjust the step size in the `Table` function to change the sampling density for `L0`, but keep in mind that it is also dependent on the sampling density for `R0` in the previous commands. Adjust the step size in `Range[-3.14, 3.14, 0.05]` for the sampling density in `Phi` but the values must be the same as those saved in `r0tab`.

Comment: When I evaluate the two `With` I get the following error: Syntax::sntxf: "TrueQ@" cannot be followed by "*(#<0&)@*First/@Differences[tab]".

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z what version are you using? The fix is probably a pair of parentheses that need inserting, but in older versions of MMA the shorthand operator for `Composition` was not present.

Comment: I use v9.0 of MMA.

Comment: I see. The solution is to replace `TrueQ@*(...)@*First` with `Composition[TrueQ, (# < 0 &), First]`. Will update in a second.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z fixed to work with v9 syntax (infix notation for `Composition` was introduced in v10).

Comment: Still the second `ListPlot`, the first and the third `With` are not free of errors.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z if you mean the errors about comparisons with complex numbers, they are to be expected. That is not a problem.

Comment: Are you, however, getting the end result that `ListPointPlot3D` gave for me?

Comment: Unfortunately no. `ListPointPlot3D` returns with no output.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z I spell-checked the code. The main culprit was `@` instead of `/@` in the routine assigning downvalues to `r0tab`. Also I have made sure, that all arguments passed to `Range` are `Real` and not `Integer` (this may lead to uncompiled evaluation). Please let me know if everything is in order now.

Comment: Now it works fine! At the end how can I print the table with the triplets?

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z remove the postfix `ListPointPlot3D` command and you'll get the table.

Comment: I will accept your answer although it seems too complicated to me. In other cases where the equations of the potential will be different I won't be able to modify the code accordingly. I still insist that my simple `For` loop is what I need but it is time consuming...

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z As was discussed in the neighboring comment threads, you can try to solve your equation for `R0` directly (but there's probably no closed form and it's time consuming), or you can solve for `L0` analytically and *numerically* invert it with respect to `R0` which is much easier. That said, if there's no closed form solution for `L0` in your other potentials, this may not help you much.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the problem symbolically for either `L0` or `R0` once and for all, and then create a table using these solutions. It's most easy to solve for `L0` since it does not appear in square roots or trigonometric functions.

```
Clear[L0,R0];
vt = L0/R0;

x0 = R0*Cos[ϕ0];
y0 = R0*Sin[ϕ0];
px0 = -vt*Sin[ϕ0];
py0 = vt*Cos[ϕ0];  
H = 1/2*(px^2 + py^2) + Vt - Ωb*(x*py - y*px);
H0 = H /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, px -> px0, py -> py0};
sol = Solve[H0 == E0, L0];
```

Since this is a quadratic equation in `L0` you will get two solutions. Choosing the first one for no particular reason, you can then generate the table of allowed values using

```
Table[{R0, ϕ0, L0 /. sol[[1]]}, {R0, 0.1, 1, 1/621}, {ϕ0, -Pi, Pi, 0.01}];
```

You will have to choose physically reasonable values for `R0` yourself. You can even inspect the solution and create a compiled version for a possible speed boost...

Comment: NO. `R0` should be computed from a given pair of `phi0` and `L0`. I don't know how to explain in detail but this has to do with maps and flows in nonlinear dynamics. It is the transformations form (\phi, L, R) to (x,y,px,py). Your solution gives completely wrong output.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z  _"I don't know how to explain in detail"_ doesn't help much to others trying to help you. Perhaps you should try harder to "explain in detail"

Comment: @belisariushassettled `H0` is a function with three parameters (phi0,L0,R0). The first two (phi0,L0) are given at the beginning of the For loop. Then we use `FindRoot` to obtain the `R0` value for a given par of (\phi0,L0).  If `R0` does not exist `FindRoot` gives a wrong answer, so at the end I use `Which` to obtain only the triplets (R0,phi0,L0) which give the desired energy level `E0`.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z That's a description of what you've done, but it doesn't explain  what you think is wrong with Marius' answer

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z so you have some implicitly defined surface in the space of `{\[Phi], L, R}`, such that `H[\[Phi], L, R] == E0`. What difference does it make, which order to sample the grid in?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The two-dimensional grid should be on the (phi,L)-plane. The why is an entire chapter of non-linear dynamics. Now each pair of (phi,L) has a specific value of `R0` which is obtained solving the energy integral. First I define a rectangular grid on the (phi,L) plane using Table. However not all the values are permitted.

Comment: For insight I suggest making your initial definitions, then running the above code instead of your `For` loop, then doing `ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate[FullSimplify[H0] == E0], {L0, -120, 520}, {R0, 0, 
  10}, {\[Phi]0, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z After the code in this answer execute the following`t = Cases[
  Flatten[Table[{\[Phi]0, L0 /. sol[[1]], R0}, {R0, 0.1, 
     10, .1}, {\[Phi]0, -Pi, Pi, 0.1}], 
   1], {_, _Real, _Real}]; Graphics3D[Point[t], BoxRatios -> 1, 
 Axes -> True]`

Comment: Result http://i.stack.imgur.com/6PG49.png

Comment: Also it would be very easy to construct an interpolating function `L0[\[Phi], R0]`  using the solution in this answer then numerically find the inverse - `R0[\[Phi], L0]`, if it is critical that you have the evenly spaced grid in L0-Phi space, rather that R0-Phi

Comment: @belisariushassettled How does this help? I want the evenly spaced grid on the (\phi,L)-plane.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Could you please post an explaining answer?

Comment: @belisariushassettled The evenly spaced grid should be on the (phi,L)-plane not on the (R,phi)-plane. This is very important. Now for the evenly spaced grid on the (phi,L)-plane I just want to know the value of R for each pair. I hope you understand what I want.